# Table- First Column Heading not aligned

Tags: tables

In the table below, the heading of the first column is slightly off for some reason. Why is this happening? How do I further make it look better overall?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccccccc@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Present\\State\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Input} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Next\\ State\end{tabular}} & Output \\
\cmidrule(l){1-2} \cmidrule(lr){5-6} \cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(l){7-7}
A          & B            & x & y        & A          & B          & z      \\ \midrule
0          & 0            & 0 & 0          & 0           & 0          & 0      \\
0          & 0            & 0 & 1          & 0           & 0          & 0      \\
0          & 0            & 1 & 0          & 1           & 1          & 0      \\
0          & 0            & 1 & 1          & 0           & 1          & 0      \\ [1ex]
0          & 1            & 0 & 0          & 0           & 0          & 0      \\
0          & 1            & 0 & 1          & 0           & 0          & 0      \\
0          & 1            & 1 & 0          & 1           & 0          & 0      \\
0          & 1            & 1 & 1          & 1           & 0          & 0      \\[1ex]
1          & 0            & 0 & 0          & 0           & 0          & 1      \\
1          & 0            & 0 & 1          & 0           & 0          & 1      \\
1          & 0            & 1 & 0          & 1           & 1          & 1      \\
1          & 0            & 1 & 1          & 0           & 1          & 1      \\[1ex]
1          & 1            & 0 & 0          & 0           & 0          & 1      \\
1          & 1            & 0 & 1          & 0           & 0          & 1      \\
1          & 1            & 1 & 0          & 1           & 1          & 1      \\
1          & 1            & 1 & 1          & 1           & 1          & 1      \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 
`\begin{tabular}{@{}ccccccc@{}}` is used as column specifiers, this must be done
with

```
\multicolumn{2}{@{}c}{....
```

too, i.e. remove the horizontal space for the first column by saying `@{}c`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccccccc@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}c}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Present\\State\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Input} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Next\\ State\end{tabular}} & Output \\
\cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(lr){5-6} \cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(l){7-7}
A          & B            & x & y        & A          & B          & z      \\ \midrule
0          & 0            & 0 & 0          & 0           & 0          & 0      \\
0          & 0            & 0 & 1          & 0           & 0          & 0      \\
0          & 0            & 1 & 0          & 1           & 1          & 0      \\
0          & 0            & 1 & 1          & 0           & 1          & 0      \\ [1ex]
0          & 1            & 0 & 0          & 0           & 0          & 0      \\
0          & 1            & 0 & 1          & 0           & 0          & 0      \\
0          & 1            & 1 & 0          & 1           & 0          & 0      \\
0          & 1            & 1 & 1          & 1           & 0          & 0      \\[1ex]
1          & 0            & 0 & 0          & 0           & 0          & 1      \\
1          & 0            & 0 & 1          & 0           & 0          & 1      \\
1          & 0            & 1 & 0          & 1           & 1          & 1      \\
1          & 0            & 1 & 1          & 0           & 1          & 1      \\[1ex]
1          & 1            & 0 & 0          & 0           & 0          & 1      \\
1          & 1            & 0 & 1          & 0           & 0          & 1      \\
1          & 1            & 1 & 0          & 1           & 1          & 1      \\
1          & 1            & 1 & 1          & 1           & 1          & 1      \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would also change `\cmidrule(l){1-2}` to `\cmidrule(r){1-2}`

Comment: @karlkoeller: Thanks, I did not notice that the first `\cmidrule` is out of place.

Comment: For a better looking I would also suggest removing `@{}` globally and use `\cmidrule(lr)...` everywhere.

Comment: Any other suggestions for making it look better?

Comment: @Surag Not by my side. :-)

Comment: the leftmost rule is still out of place ...

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Only in the screen shot, not in the code

Comment: @SoundsOfSilence -- okay, but hard to know that.  (i didn't try it.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I was too lazy to update the screen shot. I will do that tomorrow